# Is it possible to return empty list of LinkedHashMap using Mockito in a test case

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mockito

I am writing a unit test which access a public variable of LinkedHashMap in App class. I want to mock this to return empty list, how can I do that please

App has this variable

```
  public LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<QCCheck>> mapOfQCC =
        new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Unit test requires mapOfQCC to return empty list

I tried this and did not work

```
every(app.mapOfQCC).thenReturn(LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<QCCheck>>())
```

Error

```
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);
```

Thanks in advance
R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is self explanatory.
You are trying to stub field access:

```
every(app.mapOfQCC).thenReturn(LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<QCCheck>>())
```

This is not possible with Mockito.
You can only stub method calls.

You have 2 options:

- provide a getter for your field (and, possibly, make the field private). Stub the getter.
- set the field in your test. It is public. Nothing prevents you from doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<QCCheck>> keepOldIfNeed = app.mapOfQCC; // keep the list in object if you need 
app.mapOfQCC = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // this is empty
```